# How to format JSON PubSub message against Avro schema with "map" type field

Tags: json, avro, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm testing an Avro schema definition on Google Cloud Platform PubSub. I've simplified the schema down to:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "CloudEvent",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "attribute",
      "type": {
        "type": "map",
        "values": ["null", "boolean", "int", "string", "bytes"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, the JSON encoded message I'm testing with errors with "Message is invalid against schema".

This is the simplest message I'm sending that unexpectedly gives the error:

```
{
    "attribute": {
        "test": "hello"
    }
}
```

Interestingly, the following message is considered valid:

```
{
    "attribute": {}
}
```

That is expected but makes the previous message erroring even more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Avro specification on JSON encoding](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/spec.html#json_encoding). Specifically, the fact that your map has nullable values means that when they do have values, you need to specify the in a particular way, e.g.,:

```
{
    "attribute": {
        "test": {
            "string": "hello"
        }
    }
}
```